# How to escape double plus plus sign "++" in Asciidoctor Asciidoc?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

For example, if I write:

```
Notepad++ is *great*, I like Notepad++
```

it treats `++something++` as an escape construct which ignores the `*` bold and produces:

```
<p>Notepad is *great*, I like Notepad</p>
```

instead of the desired:

```
<p>Notepad++ is <strong>great</strong>, I like Notepad++</p>
```

Upstream discussion: https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/issues/1864

Tested on Asciidoctor 2.0.10.

Answer (score 7):

A few options that do what I want:

```
Notepadpass:[++] is *great*, I like Notepadpass:[++]

Notepad{blank}pass:[++] is *great*, I like Notepad{blank}pass:[++]

Notepad{plus}{plus} is *great*, I like Notepad{plus}{plus}
```

I'm not 100% sure if the `Notepadpass:[++]` is meant to work of just an accident. I think I'm just going with `{plus}{plus}`.

Where `{plus}` is documented at: https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#charref-attributes

For the specific case of `C++` there is also `{cpp}`.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use a backslash to escape the first `++`:

```
Notepad\++ is *great*, I like Notepad++
```

This works in a similar way on other formatting as well.

Comment: Tested on Asciidoctor 2.0.11.